# Button Filter to Table

Tags: sapui5

Trying to add a filter that takes a table that uses xsodata and have a dropdown that applies a filter

current code:

```
var testButton = new sap.m.Button('filterTable', {
                text: "Filter",
                tooltip: "Filter table to selection",
                icon: sap.ui.core.IconPool.getIconURI("filter"),
                press: new sap.ui.model.Filter(testTable['testColumn'], sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, "testValue")
            });
```

Comment: I can't understand what is your goal but definitely the "press" event implementation is wrong... It should be a callback function and not a filter declaration. Maybe if you can state more clearly what you want to do and what is the wrong behavior someone can help :)

Comment: basically I want to have a button that when I press the button, it filters a different data table that is a sap ui5 table structure that is populated via xsodata

Comment: Although I'm still wondering *why* you have to filter a table by pressing a button.... next question is: what kind of table are you using? sap.m.table? sap.ui.table.* ? smarttable?

Comment: just a customer requirement. The table is a sap.ui.table

Answer (score 0):

I think that this example in the SDK is what you are looking for. Take a look at how the "availability" column is declared in the XML view and at the implementation of the toggleAvailabilityFilter function in the controller.

**EDIT**: Here the basic code, as example.

How the column should be declared in the XML View:

```
        <Column
            id="columnId"
            filterProperty="Available"
            showFilterMenuEntry="false"
            defaultFilterOperator="EQ"
            filterType="sap.ui.model.type.Boolean">
            <m:Label text="Status" />
            <template>
                ...template...
            </template>
        </Column>
```

Example of button callback:

```
toggleAvailabilityFilter : function(oEvent) {
    this.byId("columnId").filter(oEvent.getParameter("pressed") ? "X" : "");
},
```